# Cookie not received on sub-domain

Tags: cookies, subdomain

- My website is on "www.upstorm.co"
- My API function is on "test.www.upstorm.co"
- Cookies with domain ".www.upstorm.co" are received
- Cookies with domain "www.upstorm.co" are not

The message from chrome devtool: "This cookie was blocked because neither did the request URL's domain exactly match the cookie's domain, nor was the request URL's domain a subdomain of the cookie's domain attribute value"

This doesn't make sense to me, because I thought "test.www.upstorm.co" was a subdomain of "www.upstorm.co"

Can someone please explain what's happening.

[image]
[image]
[image]